# React-Leaflet can't input marker position from fetching API

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

I try to input a marker position by fetching an API into the map but doesn't work.

Here is my component's code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker } from 'react-leaflet'

const Map = () => {

    const [parcels, setParcels] = useState([])
    const center = [14.881999606787934, 102.02071765448805]

    useEffect(async () => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/parcels/all')
            const getParcels = await res.json()
            setParcels(getParcels)
        } catch (e) {
            setParcels(e)
        }
    }, [])

    const position = parcels.map((parcel) => {
        return [parcel.location.coordinates[1], parcel.location.coordinates[0]]
    })

    return (
        <div>
            <MapContainer center={center} zoom={15} scrollWheelZoom={false} className="h-screen">
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; Taxmap'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
                <Marker position={position[0]}></Marker>
            </MapContainer>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Map
```

Error message from the console.
[image]

If I use console.log() to see the position[0]. It looks like normally.

```
console.log(position[0])
// result = [14.8763983, 102.0169941]
```

[image]

But when I create a variable normally. It can work.

```
const positionButArray = [14.8763983, 102.0169941]

return (
        <div>
            <MapContainer center={center} zoom={15} scrollWheelZoom={false} className="h-screen">
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; Taxmap'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
                <Marker position={positionButArray}></Marker>
            </MapContainer>
        </div>
      )
```

The result from above.
[image]

If anyone has a solution please help me. Thanks

Comment: On the first render `parcels` is an empty array. `useEffect` runs after the first render, so you need to account for the initial empty array in render.

Comment: I have solved this problem. My solution is to check if a position is not rendered it's will not return the Marker tag. Thank you, I'm going to post the solution for anyone who has the same problem as me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by just adding a ternary operator to check if a position is rendered or not. If the position is rendered, It's going to return the Marker tag. here is my solution.

```
return (
        <MapContainer center={center} zoom={15} scrollWheelZoom={false} className="h-screen">
            <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; Taxmap'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            {positions? <Marker position={positions[0]}></Marker>:null}
        </MapContainer>
    )
```

Comment: i am also integrating my local api into leaflet react . But it doesn't work ,if i use local json data hard coded then it works perfectly. can u help me?

Comment: First, check the CORS of your API. Next check whether your json field is valid or not. the position (in the geojson format of location) of the react-leaflet is swap lon, lat to lat, lon (Here is the original format of location in geojson https://geojson.org/).

Comment: Hey @Rayato159 can u ans this post? i am badly stuck with this . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73423447/my-local-api-data-is-not-working-react-leaflet